# Huge number of int arrays during java deserialization

Tags: java, deserialization

I see that there are a huge number of `int` array instances during Java deserialization using `ObjectInputStream`. I understand that this is due to creation of dependency tracking objects `(java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable$HandleList)`. As I understand, they are used to propagate ClassNotFoundException to "dependent" objects while reading an object.

I fail to understand the need to track this dependency of `ClassNotFoundException` over a target object? Why can't the implementation throw the exception right away, if the `ClassNotFoundException` is found?

There are significant bumps in transient memory usage during deserialization in one of the Java applications I work in. I have been able to attribute the spikes to the `int[]` instances after having taken a histogram using jmap.

I am trying to determine if terminating the deserialization process upon encountering the `ClassNotFoundException` should be ok. In this case, I would like to change the ObjectInputStream and use the modified class in bootstrap classpath.

I do realize that HandleTable's "entries" are absolutely required to wire any previously read objects into dependent objects read later from the stream. Just to clarify, the question has been about the significance of `java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable$HandleList`, which I fail to understand.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Raja.

Answer (score 1):

It tracks objects for the purpose of resolving circular references and ensuring that two objects A and B that point to the same object C *before* serialization do not point to two separate instances of C *after* deserialization.  *Without* tracking references, when the object hierarchy of A is deserialized it will create an instance of C, then then upon deserializing the B object hierarchy it would create another separate instance of C.  It has little to do with ClassNotFoundException.

The best you can do is throw away ObjectInputStreams as soon as you are finished deserializing one "graph" of objects, rather than reusing it for many objects.

Comment: Back-references are tracked in `java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.entries`. And yes, they are required for what you said. However, my question is regarding `java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.deps`, which is an array of HandleList. Looking through `ObjectInputStream`'s code, this is for ClassNotFoundException dependency tracking. `entries` array should be sufficient to lookup reference and wire, `deps` would not be required for this purpose. Isn't this true?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the ``deps`` is designed for ClassNotFoundException propagation.  If you are 100% certain that all your classes will be present at deserialization time, and you want to eliminate this overhead, copy the ``ObjectInputStream`` source into your own ``MyObjectInputStream`` class and rip out the dependency tracking.

Comment: Even if there is a `ClassNotFoundException`, in the changed code, I will like to throw and propagate the exception right away. So that the failure is still evident.

Comment: It hard to see how you can eliminate the creation of temporary objects in that case.  The code comment for HandleTable says:

"Once all exception information/dependencies for the handle have been
registered, the handle should be "closed" by calling the finish method
on it.  The act of finishing a handle allows the exception propagation
algorithm to aggressively prune dependency links, lessening the
performance/memory impact of exception tracking."

Seems like they are doing their best to manage memory.  But maybe you could come up with a more efficient model.